# Sencha Touch 2 + PhoneGAP VS android SDK

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am just confusing, the Sencha Touch 2 with PhoneGAP is a powerful things,
they only need to develop once then able to run in IOS and Android Operating system.

why still so many people is choosing use Android SDK to develop mobile apps?
may i know what is the limitation of Sencha Touch 2 to develop Android?

i m feeling i have no reason refuse use Sencha Touch 2 to develop mobile Apps.

just give me some guide, which one is better. Sencha Touch 2 With PhoneGAP or just use Android SDK with Eclipse ?

P/S: i have never been develop any mobile apps yet, just want to start the first apps, that is why need to research which one is better.

Comment: do some research first please

Comment: @Subash i did, but i dont understand why still so many people choosing Andriod to develop mobile apps, what is the reason? i just want to know

Comment: because it is cross-platform until the WebView of the target SDK can handle it. Yes, this is native application that runs inside a WebView. If you need to use something native that is not included in the Sencha or in the Cordova, you will have to write your own plugins. And so many other reasons.

Comment: in other words, you can't say that the WebView of the platform is better than the platform itself.

Comment: @mihail   
 
i m very confusing, what should i use? i m developing a ticketing management system which one is suitable?

Comment: as Sabash said, do a research. There are lots of people that write in their blogs about this. Like this one:  http://www.netwhisperer.com/2013/03/27/mobile-app-development-native-vs-cross-platform/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sencha Touch and Phonegap are basically javascript libraries. They are webpages use html5 and css. Phonegap uses javascript libraries to invoke native java code to access device features like camera. They are slow. 
On the other hand native apps are coded using java(android) and objective C (ios). Native apps are much faster than application built using sencha touch and phonegap.

Comment: you ar emost welcome for your ticketing management system I recommend using native android sdk.

Comment: why use native SDK? can share your opinion?

Comment: use native sdk because it has a lot of features built in and can be done using simple function calls. It provides full set of features from hardware to software. Not to mention third party libraries. By the way in some way phonegap and sencha touch are also kind of 3rd party libraries(.js and jar files). Application load and response time is also much faster in native applications.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple. You would use Sencha Touch if you are trying to build HTML5 apps. There are some limitations with HTML5 apps. But the advantage is that you have just one code base for both iOS and Android. With android SDK you get a native app with all native widgets.

Comment: i m very confusing, what should i use? i m developing a ticketing management system which one is suitable?

Comment: Depends on what the requirements are, if you are looking for a seamless experience with no lag involved in loading html, css and js then you should go for native SDK. But if you are ok with a 0.3 second delay and want to build something that is platform independent then go for Sencha and Phonegap.